Adding remove button in dynamic input fields in table
I want to add a delete row button to the dynamically generated rows that clears the subtotal of the row from the total except it will not show in the first (default) row i want it to show only in the added rows
this is my code in jsfiddle


const makeNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : +str;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
  const grandTotal = document.querySelector("[name=anstotal]");
  tbody.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    [...tbody.querySelectorAll("tr")].forEach(row => {
      const qty = makeNum(row.querySelector("[name=qty]").value);
      const price = makeNum(row.querySelector("[name=sel]").value);
      const total = qty * price
      sum += total;
      row.querySelector("[name=total]").value = total.toFixed(2);
    })
    grandTotal.value = sum.toFixed(2);
  })

  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount >= 4) {
      // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
      alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");
      return;
    }
    const newRow = tbody.querySelector("tr").cloneNode(true)
    newRow.id = "row"+rowCount;
    tbody.appendChild(newRow)
  })
})
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />

<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr id='row_0'>
      <p>
        <td>
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <input type="number" required="required" name="qty">
        </td>

        <td>
          <label>Price
          <select name="sel"  required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
          </select></label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Total <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="total"></label>
        </td>
      </p>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
add total<input type="text" name="anstotal">



i'll appreciate your help thank you.
i tried to add this eventlistener but it doesn't work
document.getElementById("delete-row").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const tableRow = $(this).closest('tr')
  const total = +tableRow.find('[name="total"]').val()
  const sum = +$('#totalOfTotals').text();
  $('#totalOfTotals').text(sum - total);
  tableRow.remove();
  row--;
})


Please include a minimal reproducible example as text, preferably as a stack snippet,  directly in your question. Links can break, making them useless to future readers. What steps have you taken to debug this? Is there an error in your console?

What steps should we take to recreate the problem? Also, you said "i tried to add this eventlistener but it doesn't work": but how isn't it working? What's expected and what's actually happening? Are there any errors?

there is no errors what i expect is whenever a new row is created the delete button eventlistener removes and clears the subtotal it's that simple.

What steps have you taken to debug this? How should we recreate the error with the code you provided here? When I run this snippet, there is no delete button.

i created a button with an id="delete-row" and used the click event that's what i did maybe if take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/camiramzi/nc1bqv4o/27/

a way to do that in pure JS / HTML5:


const 
  myTable_tBody = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')
, templateRow   = document.querySelector('#template-row')
, myTable_Total = document.querySelector('#my-table tfoot input[name="anstotal"]')
  ;
AddNewRow(); // first attempt

document.querySelector('#btn-add-row').addEventListener('click', AddNewRow);

myTable_tBody.addEventListener('input', setTotals);

myTable_tBody.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button[name="delete-row"]')) return;
  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
  setTotals();
  });

function setTotals()
  {
  let Total = 0;
  [...myTable_tBody.rows].forEach( r => 
    {
    let inTotal = r.querySelector('input[name="qty"]').valueAsNumber
                * +r.querySelector('select[name="sel"]').value;

    r.querySelector('input[name="total"]').value = inTotal;
    Total += inTotal;
    });
  myTable_Total.value = Total;
  }
  
function AddNewRow()
  {
  if (myTable_tBody.rows.length < 4)
    myTable_tBody.append( document.importNode(templateRow.content, true) );
  else
    alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");
  }
table {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
  background      : darkblue;
  border-collapse : separate;
  border-spacing  : 1px;
  }
th {
  background-color : aquamarine;
  padding          : .8em .4em;
  }
td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .8em .4em;
  text-align       : right;
  }

/* hide the delete button in case of only one row. */ 
table#my-table tbody tr:only-child button[name="delete-row"] {
  visibility : hidden;
  }
<button id="btn-add-row">Add new row</button>
<table id="my-table">
  <thead> <tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th></th></tr> </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
  <tfoot> <tr><td colspan="3"> TOTAL = <input type="text" name="anstotal" value="0" readonly></td><td></td></tr> </tfoot>
</table>

<template id="template-row">
  <tr> 
    <td> <input type="number" name="qty" value="0" min="0"> </td>
    <td>
      <select name="sel" >
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose a price</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>      
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="total" value="0" readonly> </td>
    <td> <button name="delete-row">Delete</button> </td>
  </tr>
</template>




thank you this is what i want is there a way to not show the delete button in the first row.

You could use CSS to hide the one in the first row.

i forgot about css thank you @mykaf

@BoualiRamzi added CSS to hide the delete button in case of only one row.
